# Trigger transition on child element, when hovering parent

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a menu, which I want to animate using css3. When you hover the main-menu, I want to slide in the sub-menu. However I don't know where to put the `transition` property, to make it animate both ways.

Here is an example of it working correctly, but only on hover in.

http://jsfiddle.net/34kcamjv/

But it just snaps off, when I end my hover, instead of sliding up.

I've tried putting the `transition` on the `#sub` element, but then nothing happens.

Here is the css:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#sub {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index: -10;
    //If transition is put here, nothing happens
}

#menu:hover > #sub {
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="main">MAINMENU</div>
        <div id="sub">SUBMENU</div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do a mistake, a typo or something like that? Because this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34kcamjv/1/) is working fine and there the `transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;` is placed at the `//If transition is put here, nothing happens`

Comment: @LongInt: The correct place is on the `#sub` only. It should work provided you had not made any other mistakes. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/34kcamjv/2/) is a sample.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. On latest Chrome, Windows 7. But it does work in Firefox and IE.... must be a Chrome thing then.

Comment: @LongInt: I am on the latest Opera which also uses Webkit so I am surprised that it doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Just now checked in the most recent Chrome version (Version 42.0.2300.2 dev-m) on Windows 8.1 and it does work.

Comment: @LongInt using latest Chrom stable (40.0.2214.111)  and works fine here. So there must be  something else wrong with you browser.

Comment: Yeah, it must be some odd bug. Turned all extensions off, and still no luck. Works in Chrome Canary though...

Comment: chromium works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on my Chrome browser. The code worked as expected on IE11, Firefox and Chrome Canary. Other users could not replicate the bug on their versions of Chrome.

Comment: your example in the question only slides one way, did the example in my answer slide both ways or not at all?

Comment: I had already tried your solution before posting the question (as I noted in the code). Your code did not work on my Chrome browser (but on all other browsers) - that is why I have concluded it was my browser, that was behaving oddly.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/34kcamjv/4/

Set the transition on the element itself, so when you unhover it returns to the original state with a transition aswell...

```
#menu > #sub {
    transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding transition with the proper vender prefixes?

```
-webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
```

Just a thought.